# C- Preprocessor defining a macro

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Hello I need a help in defining a macro dependent on a variable.
For Eg:

```
#if TEMP
   #define COUNT  5
#else
   #define COUNT  6
#endif
```

TEMP will be set in a function.
Eg:

```
void func()
{
    TEMP = 1;
}
```

Setting the count macro and defining temp are in different files.

Can anyone help me on this?

TIA
Sowmya

Comment: `define`s are meant for the 'preprocessor'.

Comment: You can't set preprocessor macros like normal variables, especially not runtime. The preprocessor is run as a separate step in the compilation process, before the actual compiler.

Comment: Why defining COUNT as a macro and not a variable too? Btw, you cannot put a variable name in a `define` preprocessor command.

Comment: No offense intended, but you obviously don't know what you're doing.  I suggest you forget about the preprocessor and `#define`, and try using variables `bool temp = false; int count = temp ? 5 : 6; ... temp = true;` etc..  If you have a reason for not just doing that, please share it.

Comment: Tony, Count is not an integer. It is actually enabling and disabling gpio depending on TEMP. So I cannot use bool type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. `TEMP` will only be set on runtime and is not available for the preprocessing. You could use the `-DTEMP` as a compiler flag to define it if you need `COUNT` to be `5`. You'd have to change your code into the following:

```
#ifdef TEMP
  #define COUNT 5
#else
  #define COUNT 6
#endif
```

Comment: I wanted my application to decide the COUNT value depending on variable TEMP. Thank you all for your reply.

Comment: And that is what it does. If `TEMP` is defined, then `COUNT` equals 5, otherwise `COUNT` equals 6. If you mean you want the value of `COUNT` to depend on the value of `TEMP`, you should see if `gcc` supports that.

Comment: I am an embedded developer. In the application, the Variable TEMP will be set during run time by reading gpio pins.     Is it not possible to set TEMP and define macros ?

Comment: Ah in that case I am afraid this solution will not work, check out the comment by @Tony-D above. Basically `COUNT` should be a variable/function rather than a defined constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Macros are resolved during compilation, so a runtime change like setting a variable cannot impact them.